# SPARQL Attribute Search (MarkLogic)

Tags: sparql, marklogic, semantics

I have been trying to do attribute searching in sparql, for now I have a solution with using CTS to prepare the necessary sem triples before hand as shown in the codes below

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace sem = "http://marklogic.com/semantics" at "/MarkLogic/semantics.xqy";

sem:sparql('
SELECT *
WHERE {?s ?p ?o .}
',
(),
(),
cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName("sem:subject"), xs:QName("attri_name"), "Robert")
)
```

However, what I want to know is if I can actually do all of this inside a simple sparql query? Maybe something such as

```
sem:sparql('
SELECT *
WHERE {?s ?p ?o .
      FILTER (get all sem triples with attri_value for sem:subject that contains "Robert")}',
(),
(),
()
)
```

For now I understand that `FILTER cts:contains` can be used as it returns a boolean (true/false) to help determine if a certain row suits the condition but this cant be fulfilled with `element-attribute-value-query`. At the same time when using `FILTER cts...` inside a SPARQL query only the targeted data which mainly consists of text/date/time data will be queried.

Finally, an example of the data being used can be seen below.

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sem:triples xmlns:sem="http://marklogic.com/semantics">
<sem:triple>
<sem:subject attri_name="Robert">http://dbpedia.org/resource/Robert_Shayne</sem:subject>
<sem:predicate>http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/description</sem:predicate>
<sem:object xml:lang="en">Film, Television actor</sem:object>
</sem:triple>
</sem:triples>
```

Comment: Have you considered saving that information as another triple instead?

Comment: I don't know MarkLogic at all, but "standard" RDF resources cannot hold attributes like in your sample data. As @grtjn suggests, you should save this information in another RDF triple.

Comment: @grtjn, I have considered saving that information as another triple but I wanted to see if MarkLogic can accomplish something like [neo4j property graph](https://neo4j.com/developer/graph-database/#property-graph) where attributes are stored within each node, these attributes can then be used/accessed in queries to generate a certain output.

Comment: Those properties are linked to predicates, rather than subjects. If you attach them to subjects, you might as well just use another triple. If you want to decorate a predicate, you can also do it more traditionally, by generating a unique predicate id/uri, and then using that as subject for a new set of triples, where one represents the type of the predicate, and the others will represent the properties..

Comment: That said, it can be really useful to combine triple and document approach in MarkLogic, but I'd recommend using it the other way around, and have a document at the center, with embedded (literal) or derived (using TDE) triples linked to it..

Comment: @grtjn, after reading up more on RDF and LPG I would like to clarify on certain things. Firstly, is [this](https://s3.amazonaws.com/dev.assets.neo4j.com/wp-content/uploads/20170617195034/RDF-model-graphconnect.png) about RDF 
node and edges having no internal structure really true? Next, I would like to confirm if what you said on "document at the center.... triples linked to it" is accurately referring to [this](https://s3.amazonaws.com/dev.assets.neo4j.com/wp-content/uploads/20170617200105/RDF-Modeling-Workaround.png) work around. Thank you for your time.

Comment: The second link is exactly describing what I referred to as 'decorate a predicate more traditionally'. Having a document at the center is not the same thing though. A document can contain many related properties, in almost any kind of shape. That is more like aggregating triples related to one subject into one document.